# How to help implement more logic in my joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have some logic currently in my sql statement that takes away all punctuation so I can compare the two fields easily; however, I am having an issue now where my A table has a bank name of `BBVA BANCOMER SA INSTITUCION DE BANCA MULTIPLE, GRUPO FINANCIERO BBVA BANCOMER` and my B table has the Institution name of, `BBVA BANCOMER` and other variations that do not match Table A.

I have multiple different bank names with this issue.

How do I add a `like '%<bank name here>%'` into my join to find all the matches? Thank you.

```
SELECT B.RECORD_KEY, A.[R.F.C.], A.[Bank Name]
FROM srcENRICH.dbo.FICO_BNKA_RFC_E AS A
INNER JOIN dbo.BM_BNKA_SRCENRICH_BM_SWIFT_S AS B
   ON REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(sA.[Bank Name], ',', ''), '.', ''), '-', ''), '+', ''), '/', ''), '''', ''), '&', 'AND'), '(', ''), ')', '') 
                    = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(B.INSTITUTION_NAME, ',', ''), '.', ''), '-', ''), '+', ''), '/', ''), '''', ''), '&', 'AND'), '(', ''), ')', '')
```

I was thinking maybe a `WHERE` clause; however, I don't know how to compare the two fields together based on a `LIKE` function. If I found a solution for this, would I need to do the same for each bank needed?

---

I am currently getting 31 matches soley based off of taking punctuation out; however, my expected output is above 1,650. This is because BANCOMER has no matches anywhere solely based on exact name, however, when I go into Table B database, there are ~1600 outputs for `LIKE '%BANCOMER%'`. I need to implement a `LIKE` function.

Comment: It might help if you gave concrete examples of the data you have and what you expect as the output.

Comment: `on replace((((())))) = replace ((((())))) or a.[bank name] like b.[bank name] + '%'`  Or you can combine those ideas `on replace((((())))) like replace((((())))) + '%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is a lookup table that gives you like values.  Then you can populate that table in a way that drives your business rules.

For example consider the following LOOKUP table.

```
CODE VALUE
---- -----
1    BOA
1    BANK OF AMERICA
2    CITIBANK
2    CITI
```

Then you can have a query like this:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLEA A
 JOIN LOOKUP ALOOK ON A.BANK = ALOOK.VALUE
 JOIN LOOKUP BLOOK ON ALOOK.CODE = BLOOK.CODE
 JOIN TABLEB B     ON B.BANK= BLOOK.BANK
```

Now we have A and B joining on BOA = BANK OF AMERICA and CITIBANK = CITI

You can continue to add new entities to the LOOKUP table as you "find" them and want them to join together.

Using a lookup table in this way on SQL servers is **much** faster than running a function (or multiple) like you are in the sample code.

Comment: Ended up doing this, thank you! Great solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional conditions to the JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
JOIN T2
  ON  T1.fieldA = T2.fieldA
 AND  T1.fieldB = Somefunction(T2.fieldB)
```

Comment: Can I do this? ```SELECT *
FROM T1
JOIN T2
  ON  T1.fieldA = T2.fieldA
 AND  SomeFunction(T1.fieldA) = Somefunction(T2.fieldA)```

Comment: You probably need `OR` -- but yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is sufficient to use `like`:

```
SELECT B.RECORD_KEY, A.[R.F.C.], A.[Bank Name]
FROM srcENRICH.dbo.FICO_BNKA_RFC_E br JOIN
     dbo.BM_BNKA_SRCENRICH_BM_SWIFT_S ms
     ON br.bankname LIKE '%' + bs.bankname + '%'
```

If is not clear which bank is which -- that is which is the shorter name and which is the more complex name.

Answer (score 0):

How many non-matched bank names do you have? Will you get more bank info?

Sadly there is no perfect way to solve this. Your replaced name should work to some degree, but if there are some typos or the name is truncated e.g. "LLC" and "LL", the replaced name is still not reliable.

I used to have the same issue, for example, when I get some new bank information, it's not recognized to the bank table.

How I solved my issue:

1. Create a table to store all alias name and correct name for the bank (Manual effort will be needed)
   Column: Correct name, alias name, ...
2. Write a trigger to track all the changes made. If someone change the bank name, that change will be automatically stored in the above table.
3. As more and more bank info is collected, it will be matched up easily.